# Ubuntu 16.04. Failed to fetch... .deb Not Found

Tags: 16.04

New to Ubuntu. Today I decided to rebuild my dockerfile from  Ubuntu 16,04 and get this errors

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-common_5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-5.7_5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client_5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

There were no problems during the assembly yesterday.

Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM  ubuntu:16.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -yq mysql-client
```

I know decision like

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.7
```

I can’t understand where the files from the official repo. Maybe this is a temporary problem?

Comment: I looked up one package and you're requesting an old/out-dated version (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=zlib1g-dev)  What is the command? and I'd check your mirror as your paste should say 1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.3  (not 4.1)  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. There really was an old Ubuntu image. I deleted the old image (docker rmi ubuntu:16.04) and downloaded the new image